# Check position of loader

Tags: css, google-chrome

I want to check the position of loader (circle loading) to fix it at the middle of the screen.

But whenever I run the project in development mode, I can't see the loader for a long time as the page loads, content appears and the loader  disappears.

Is there any method to see the loader for a longer time?

Answer (score 0):

1st you need to provide code to be able to fix it
2nd did you try inspect element?
3rd you may wan to use jquery for that (its very easy)

Javascript file:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {

    $(".loader .inner").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(".loader").fadeOut(750);
    });

});
```

HTML file Make sure to put it under the body opening tag like this

```html
<body>
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
<!-- rest of the code .. -->
```

CSS file:

```css
.loader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.loader .inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../images/loader.gif) center center no-repeat;
}
```

this is 1 of the simplest ways to do it (there is tons of ways)

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Develop your loader as individual component which has no relation to your project flow, update it as per new requirements and then embed in your project.

As each component has different logic behind holding its state inside project, developing those component as standalone is better than looking for how to hold that specific state inside project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome to simulate internet speed directly.

See this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/network-conditions